# rosrun UWSim error

Tags: ros, rosrun, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy,

I have finally installed ros and UWSim. After completing "rosmake UWSim" it said 49/49 something finished with success.
Than I entered in Terminal "rosrun UWSim UWSim" and this is what is written:

**[ERROR] [1363105450.041717753]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...**

What should I do now? Im without any ideas...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57901/rosrun-uwsim-error/) by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start the core with `roscore`.

It might be a good idea to go through the basic ROS tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3